# Keyboard layout indicator just disappeared today!

Tags: 12.04, indicator, keyboard-layout, input-language

Last night everything worked fine but today when I turned on my system I saw that keyboard layout indicator at the top of screen is disappeared!!! even I cannot change it by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> like before!!!

In login screen it is there but when I login to my user it just gone!!!

I added my keyboard layout again but nothing changed !!1

Help please

Comment: What keyboard layouts do you use?

Comment: Must be a bug... I haven't be able to change my layout in the last 2-3 days, and no indicator is visible too. Don't know what updates caused the breaking though... Is your layout indicator visible in the login screen?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you use *English (US)* - `us` and *Kurdish (Iran, Arabic-Latin)* - `ir\tku_ara` layouts, just run the following command in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
gsettings get org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts ['us', 'ir\tku_ara']
```

and keyboard layout indicator should appear.

Some explanations: the keyboard layout indicator it doesn't show if you have set only one keyboard layout, but when you set more than one keyboard layout, this will appear.

Comment: it did not work!!!